# ASP.Net MVC Application with SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application in which I am trying to get SQL from an ADO.Net Entity Data model to be displayed within my `index.cshtml`

My home controller controller behind this page is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using TemplateBootstrap.Models;

namespace TemplateBootstrap.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Within my `index.cshtml` there is a lot of HTML currently I have hard coded in my navigation headings and content that are stored within 5 tables of my database for example Main Navigation 1/2, Side Navigation 1/2 and Content.

Below is the SQL statement use for the MainNavLevel1.
`SELECT [MNavID], [DisplayLabel],[Priority] FROM [MainNavLevel1] ORDER BY [Priority]"`

This is an example I am using one table with no SQL code.

```
controller: namespace TemplateBootstrap.Controllers
{
    public class NavigationController : Controller
    {
        private AskHoltsEntities db = new AskHoltsEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.AH_Corp_MainNavLevel1.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Using this view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TemplateBootstrap.Models.AH_Corp_MainNavLevel1>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DisplayLabel)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.URL)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayLabel) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.URL)</td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I need help to change the code or additions (class) made to put my SQL statements to retrieve the data from multiple tables.

Comment: Any ideas about what?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You need to specify what you want to show on your page for us to understand the goal.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Where I should put the SQL query to help do this?

Comment: Are you using any ORMs or are you using ado.net?

Comment: I was going to use ADO.net the only problem is limited support.

Comment: What you mean by limited support? Btw you can create stored procedure and call it with ado.net or ORM such as EF .

Comment: Hey Dude, I am not trying to be rude, i remember the day where i was in your shoes. If you are not sure where/how to get started. I would recommend doing some Quick learning before you start working on the application. Here is the link to the free MVC tutorial by plularsight. This is very helpful and very popular and would take a day to get started and work along .https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc4-building

Answer (score 2):

Basic ADO.NET connections haven't really changed at all within MVC. They still rely on things like [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) objects and their associated commands, which you can use without issue in MVC (as long as you have a connection string).

If you wanted to build a simply query, it might look like the following if you wanted to target a specific table (that may / may not be in your context) within your Controller Action (or an abstracted class that would handle data access exclusively):

```
// Build your connection
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("{your-connection-string-here"}))
{
     // Build your query
     var query = "SELECT [MNavID], [DisplayLabel],[Priority] FROM [MainNavLevel1] ORDER BY [Priority]";
     // Create a command to execute your query
     using(var command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
     {
          // Open the connection
          connection.Open();

          // Execute your query here (in this case using a data reader)
          using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
                // Create a list of items to use in your View (assumes this class exists)
                var navigationLabels = new List<NavigationLabel>();

                // Iterate through your results
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                      // Build a navigation item for each row returned from
                      // your query
                      navigationLabels.Add(new NavigationLabel(){
                           MNavID = reader["MNavID"],
                           DisplayLabel = reader["DisplayLabel"],
                           Priority = reader["Priority"]
                      });
                }

                // Pass your labels to your View
                return View(navigationLabels);
          }
     }
}
```

This assumes that you have a class that actually mimics your database structure and contains similar properties that you can map to `NavigationLabel` in this case.

If you were using something like Entity Framework and already had these entities, then you could presumably use something like the following code to pull your appropriate items from the context :

```
using(var context = new DbEntities())
{
       var navigationLabels = context.NavigationLabels
                                     .OrderBy(n => n.Priority)
                                     .ToList();
       return View(navigationLabels);
}
```

Comment: Hi is this code in my controller? as this is where I am not sure where is should go?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in your Controller (or if you prefer to abstract it a bit, you could make another class to handle data access and call it through that class).

Comment: It would be better if you abstract it separating the data layer from the business logic

Comment: @jamiedanq can you show me how to do this please?

Comment: @RionWilliams thank you very much for you answer I have tried to add the using (var context = new ....) part but it comes up with an error :(

Comment: Are you sure that your connection string is correct? It should be pointing to your database that contains the tables that were referenced earlier.

Comment: @RionWilliams I am using ADO.Net entity model. I have inserted private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

Comment: I have just tried to create a new class and insert the code above into this but my mvc application didn't like it! any suggestions

Comment: You could use the following [very hastily thrown together example](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/f43ca4a21c27e8469f448136d5c6ae61) which would be called via `DataAccess.GetNavigationLabels()`.

Comment: @RionWilliams is this just added into a class in the model or would this be under a controller? I don't know if you might already have answer it thanks.

Comment: You could make that into its own class and then in your Controller, you would just need to call `var navItems = DataAccess.GetNavigationLabels();` and then pass those labels to your View via `return View(navItems);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109764/discussion-between-terrortot38-and-rion-williams).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare your ApplicationDbContext object. (hint: the ApplicationDbContext will be derived from your connection string in your startup.cs or wherever you may have it.) I actually have a blog post step by step tutorial at http://blog.meemsit.com/post/2016/04/03/how-to-make-a-mvc-web-application-using-asp-net5-mvc-6-and-entity-framework-7 I think this might answer some of your deeper questions that you may have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using TemplateBootstrap.Models;

namespace TemplateBootstrap.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
        //This will provide your context to your HomeController
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    //Then declare your public context.
    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.MainNavLevel1.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Then go to your Index.cshtml and call your model at the top and use Html helpers to display the information.

```
   @model IEnumerable<TemplateBootstrap.Models.MainNavLevel1>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DisplayLabel)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayLabel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

and you should have a ApplicationDbContext class in your models folder which is where you would use fluentAPI to define any special things about how this should be wired up.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using TemplateBootstrap.Models;

namespace TemplateBootstrap.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            //Put SQL Statements Here
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
        public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my application doesn't like ApplicationDbContext _context; do you know why this could be?

Comment: What part does it not like, the ApplicationDbContext or the _context?